# Discrete value extract from raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, point, extract

I am trying to extract values from a landuse raster layer to a point shapefile. However, when I use either [Extract Multi Values to Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-multi-values-to-points.htm) or the [Extract Values to Points tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm), it returns pixel values that do not resemble the land use classification. For example, the land use code system looks like this:

- 1.1 Nature conservation
- 1.1.1 Strict nature reserves
- 1.1.2 Wilderness area
- etc.

How can I extract this information from the raster into a point feature class?

Comment: Why not use "11", "111", "112", etc.? What values are you getting that are problematic?

Comment: You need lookup table between integers stored and description text. Should come with raster.